# Ubuntu 20.10 doesn't awake properly from sleep

Tags: 20.10

I recently upgraded from 20.04 to 20.10 on my Ubuntu only laptop. I run Ubuntu on Wayland since 18.10.

Since upgrading I have noticed that my Dash to Dock is no longer available after my laptop has been wakened from sleep mode and that any opened programs are also no longer available in the GUI. This is extremely inconvenient and I have switched off the sleep mode until the problem can be resolved.

I do get the "Problem with Ubuntu" message either if I keep the laptop on and launch programs with the terminal or if I reboot, and I always send the report.